# Recovering Lightroom edits after a system hard drive failure

Tags: lightroom-5

I had a hard drive failure, but I had everything backed up. I have replaced the faulty drive and restored the Lightroom images and catalog from the backup. I can see all the images in Lightroom but none of the star ratings or edits were restored. I was wondering what else I can do to recover back to where I was before the failure.

Answer (score 1):

First two things I always try when the catalog seems out of sync:

1) optimize the catalog, which also checks for and fixes (or reports) corruption. Just in case.

2) find the folder with the images in the left sidebar of Lightroom and right-click on it. That brings up a menu and you can pick "Synchronize Folder" action. it brings up a dialog; make sure the 'import' and 'sync metadata' options are checked. fire it off and if the folder is large, go get a soda...

I think it's a good idea to turn on "automatically write changes into XMP" so that updates end up in the image files where you can recover if a catalog crashes badly -- but it can slow down Lightroom if you make edits on a big set of images and/or use slow hard drives. That makes this kind of data more recoverable if the catalog (or disk) crashes.